# Google Charts dashboard: Baseline not automatically adjusted in a Bubble Chart for bottom 40% of values

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I'm just starting my adventure with Google Charts and I have a requirement to visualize over 100 points of data in a [bubble chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart). This naturally makes the chart harder to read, so I did some research and realized I can make the exploration of the data easier by adding filtering options (which are possible when charts are created as [dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)).

I discovered a behavior that I'm not able to fix:

- Imagine the values in one attribute can range from 0 to 100
- The displayed data points can be filtered using a [dashboard control](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#numberrangefilter) of the `NumberRangeFilter` type which has a minimal value of 0 and maximal value of 100 (asigned automatically)
- **When the minimal value is smaller or equal 40, the baseline stays at 0**
- When the minimal value is greater than or equal 41, the baseline is dynamically adjusted to reflect the minimal value found in that range (for example if the selected range is 51-100, then the baseline will be displayed starting from 60)

The problem in visual form:
[image]

The only fix that comes to mind would be to force the `vAxis.baseline` attribute of the `options` object as automatic, but that's supposedly the default value and according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#configuration-options) this only accepts numbers.

Does anyone know how I could force the chart to be updated even for the slightest changes with the control in the dashboard?

---

Full code for reference:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {

  // Create our data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'X', 'Y', 'T', 'S'],
    ['A', 0, 0, "-", 3],
    ['B', 20, 20, "-", 2],
    ['C', 30, 30, "-", 1],
    ['D', 40, 40, "-", 1],
    ['E', 50, 50, "-", 2],
    ['F', 41, 60, "-", 1],
    ['G', 80, 50, "-", 2],
    ['H', 50, 80, "-", 2],
    ['I', 90, 90, "-", 2],
    ['J', 100, 100, "-", 4],
    ['K', 50, 70, "-", 1],
    ['L', 70, 50, "-", 1],
    ['M', 10, 50, "-", 2],
    ['N', 50, 10, "-", 2],
    ['X', 100, 50, "-", 2],
    ['Y', 50, 100, "-", 2]
  ]);
  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var yAxisControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Y'
    }
  });


  var bubbleChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'BubbleChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      width: 300,
      height: 350,
      chartArea: {
        left: 50,
        top: 20,
        width: 250,
        height: 250
      },
      legend: 'right',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'X Axis'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Y Axis'
      },
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind(yAxisControl, bubbleChart);

  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
.dash {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div" class="dash">
  <div id="filter_div2"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```